# Math Practice issues

Tags: java, random, operators

I have to do this project for my programming class that requires us to prompt the user for how many math problems they want to solve, the difficulty they desire (easy or hard), and then to randomly ask math problems based on their input. For some reason, I cannot get the code to operate past asking for the difficulty level. I think the issue is the way I'm trying to randomly select operators, but I'm not sure. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class MathPractice {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int answer;
    int count = 0;
    int solution;
    int correct = 0;
    int numEasy1 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int numEasy2 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int numHard1 = rand.nextInt(20) - 9;
    int numHard2 = rand.nextInt(20) - 9;
    int sign = rand.nextInt(4);

    System.out.print("How many problems do you want? ");
    int number = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("What level difficulty would you prefer (easy/hard)? ");
    String difficulty = keyboard.next();
    if (difficulty == "easy" || difficulty == "Easy") {
        while (count < number) {
            if (sign == '0') {
                System.out.print(numEasy1+" + "+numEasy2+" = ");
                answer = keyboard.nextInt();
                solution = numEasy1 + numEasy2;
                count++;
                if (answer == solution) {
                    System.out.println("Correct!");
                    correct++;
                    count++;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Incorrect. Correct answer is "+solution);
                        count++;
                    }
            } else if (sign == '1') {
                System.out.print(numEasy1+" - "+numEasy2+" = ");
                answer = keyboard.nextInt();
                solution = numEasy1 - numEasy2;
                count++;
                if (answer == solution) {
                    System.out.println("Correct!");
                    correct++;
                    count++;
                    } else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect. Correct answer is "+solution);
                    count++;
                }
            } else if (sign == '2') {
                System.out.print(numEasy1+" * "+numEasy2+" = ");
                answer = keyboard.nextInt();
                solution = numEasy1 * numEasy2;
                count++;
                if (answer == solution) {
                    System.out.println("Correct!");
                    correct++;
                    count++;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect. Correct answer is "+solution);
                    count++;
                }
            } else if (sign =='3') {
                System.out.print(numEasy1+" / "+numEasy2+" = ");
                answer = keyboard.nextInt();
                solution = numEasy1 / numEasy2;
                count++;
                if (answer == solution) {
                    System.out.println("Correct!");
                    correct++;
                    count++;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect. Correct answer is "+solution);
                    count++;
                }
            }//inner if statement
        }//while loop
    } else if (difficulty == "hard" || difficulty == "Hard") {  
        while (count < number) {
            if (sign == '0') {
                System.out.print(numHard1+" + "+numHard2+" = ");
                answer = keyboard.nextInt();
                solution = numHard1 + numHard2;
                count++;
                if (answer == solution) {
                    System.out.println("Correct!");
                    correct++;
                    count++;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect. Correct answer is "+solution);
                    count++;
                }
            } else if (sign == '1') {
                System.out.print(numHard1+" - "+numHard2+" = ");
                answer = keyboard.nextInt();
                solution = numHard1 - numHard2;
                count++;
                if (answer == solution) {
                    System.out.println("Correct!");
                    correct++;
                    count++;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect. Correct answer is "+solution);
                    count++;
                }
            } else if (sign == '2') {
                System.out.print(numHard1+" * "+numHard2+" = ");
                answer = keyboard.nextInt();
                solution = numHard1 * numHard2;
                count++;
                if (answer == solution) {
                    System.out.println("Correct!");
                    correct++;
                    count++;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect. Correct answer is "+solution);
                    count++;
                }
            } else if (sign == '3') {
                System.out.print(numHard1+" / "+numHard2+" = ");
                answer = keyboard.nextInt();
                solution = numHard1 / numHard2;
                count++;
                if (answer == solution) {
                    System.out.println("Correct!");
                    correct++;
                    count++;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect. Correct answer is "+solution);
                    count++;
                }
            }//inner if statement
        }//while loop   
    } //if statement
    System.out.println("You got "+correct+" correct out of "+number+".");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `nextLine`. which will consume new line character after the input

```
    System.out.print("How many problems do you want? ");
    int number = keyboard.nextInt();
    keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("What level difficulty would you prefer (easy/hard)? ");
    String difficulty = keyboard.next();
```

and use equals method to compare string values ,`==` will compare the object reference.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, now that I have this part working, I've realized that my code is just generating the same math problem over and over again. Neither the number nor the operator changes. What do I do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Your code `if (sign == '0') {` is comparing an integer form the rand.nextInt() function to a char. Change `'0'` to just `0` for all your if statements

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `if (difficulty == "easy" || difficulty == "Easy")` to `if (difficulty.equalsIgnoreCase("easy"))` and do the same for the "hard" loop.

Also, you have `sign` declared as an `int` but you compare it as if it were a `char`. change all your `(sign == '3')` lines to `(sign == 3)` and you should be good.